# fetch files from windows to remote host using ansible doesn't get copied properly

Tags: python, ansible

I'm using Ansible through Python to fetch logs from remote Windows host. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as Ansible is not able to fetch log files.

This is my Python call:

```
status = ansible_runner.run_ansible_playbook(
            "fetch-windows-cbl-logs.yml",
            extra_vars={
                "log_full_path": log_full_path,
                "log_file": log_file
            }
        )
```

This is my Ansible playbook:

```
stop-fetch-windows-cbl-logs.yml

- name: Getting directory of files
  win_shell: Get-ChildItem | where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | foreach { $_.Name }
  args:
    chdir: "{{ log_file }}"
  register: files_to_copy

- name: Debug Msg
  debug: msg="Copying logs at - {{ log_full_path }}"

- name: Fetch logs
  fetch: src={{ log_file }} dest={{ log_full_path }} fail_on_missing=yes validate_checksum=yes flat=yes
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
```

Called from Another playbook -

```
 - name: Windows - Stop TestServer   
   hosts: windows   
   vars:
     log_full_path:
     log_file:


   tasks:
     - include: tasks/stop-fetch-windows-cbl-logs.yml
```

I'm getting below error:

```
Running playbook: libraries/provision/ansible/playbooks/fetch-windows-cbl-logs.yml

    PLAY [Windows - Stop TestServer] ***********************************************

    TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
    ok: [win1]

    TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    ok: [win1] => {
        "msg": "Copying from C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\b0bd6c4c-e257-44c1-aeeb-7188f65af9d0_75cr2b68sm664\\AC\\Temp\\log_1556888740.22821\\cbl_debug_1556888740255.cbllog to /tmp/cbl-logs/"
    }

    TASK [Fetch logs] **************************************************************
    An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    fatal: [win1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error_record": {"CategoryInfo": {"Activity": "Test-Path", "Category": 0, "Reason": "ArgumentException", "TargetName": "", "TargetType": ""}, "ErrorDetails": null, "Exception": {"Data": {}, "HResult": -2147024809, "HelpLink": null, "InnerException": null, "Message": "Illegal characters in path.", "ParamName": null, "Source": "mscorlib", "StackTrace": "   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)\r\n   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.IsReservedDeviceName(String destinationPath)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeItemExists(String path, Boolean& isDirectory, Exception& exception)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeDirectoryExists(String path)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.IsItemContainer(CmdletProvider providerInstance, String path, CmdletProviderContext context)", "TargetSite": {"Attributes": 147, "CallingConvention": 1, "ContainsGenericParameters": false, "CustomAttributes": "", "DeclaringType": "System.IO.Path", "IsAbstract": false, "IsAssembly": true, "IsConstructor": false, "IsFamily": false, "IsFamilyAndAssembly": false, "IsFamilyOrAssembly": false, "IsFinal": false, "IsGenericMethod": false, "IsGenericMethodDefinition": false, "IsHideBySig": true, "IsPrivate": false, "IsPublic": false, "IsSecurityCritical": false, "IsSecuritySafeCritical": false, "IsSecurityTransparent": true, "IsSpecialName": false, "IsStatic": true, "IsVirtual": false, "MemberType": 8, "MetadataToken": 100669730, "MethodHandle": "System.RuntimeMethodHandle", "MethodImplementationFlags": 0, "Module": "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary", "Name": "CheckInvalidPathChars", "ReflectedType": "System.IO.Path", "ReturnParameter": "Void ", "ReturnType": "void", "ReturnTypeCustomAttributes": "Void "}}, "FullyQualifiedErrorId": "System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand", "InvocationInfo": {"BoundParameters": {}, "CommandOrigin": 1, "DisplayScriptPosition": null, "ExpectingInput": false, "HistoryId": 1, "InvocationName": "Test-Path", "Line": "ElseIf (Test-Path -PathType Container $src)\n", "MyCommand": {"CommandType": 8, "DefaultParameterSet": "Path", "Definition": "\r\nTest-Path [-Path] <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-PathType <TestPathType>] [-IsValid] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]\r\n\r\nTest-Path -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-PathType <TestPathType>] [-IsValid] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]\r\n", "HelpFile": "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll-Help.xml", "ImplementingType": "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand", "Module": "Microsoft.PowerShell.Management", "ModuleName": "Microsoft.PowerShell.Management", "Name": "Test-Path", "Noun": "Path", "Options": 1, "OutputType": "System.Boolean", "PSSnapIn": null, "ParameterSets": "[-Path] <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-PathType <TestPathType>] [-IsValid] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>] -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-PathType <TestPathType>] [-IsValid] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]", "Parameters": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata]", "RemotingCapability": 1, "Source": "Microsoft.PowerShell.Management", "Verb": "Test", "Version": "3.1.0.0", "Visibility": 0}, "OffsetInLine": 9, "PSCommandPath": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1556892651.2-106929474671208\\slurp.ps1", "PSScriptRoot": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1556892651.2-106929474671208", "PipelineLength": 0, "PipelinePosition": 0, "PositionMessage": "At C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1556892651.2-106929474671208\\slurp.ps1:285 char:9\r\n+ ElseIf (Test-Path -PathType Container $src)\r\n+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "ScriptLineNumber": 285, "ScriptName": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1556892651.2-106929474671208\\slurp.ps1", "UnboundArguments": []}, "PSMessageDetails": null, "PipelineIterationInfo": [], "ScriptStackTrace": "at <ScriptBlock>, C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1556892651.2-106929474671208\\slurp.ps1: line 285\r\nat <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 4", "TargetObject": null}, "failed": true, "msg": "Illegal characters in path."}
        to retry, use: --limit @/Users/hemant/couchbase/couchbase/mobile-testkit/libraries/provision/ansible/playbooks/fetch-windows-cbl-logs.retry
```

After Resolving the above error, ansible playbook is saying that it's copying files but I can't see any files copied there -

```
Running playbook: libraries/provision/ansible/playbooks/fetch-windows-cbl-logs.yml

PLAY [Windows - Stop TestServer] ***********************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [win1]

TASK [Getting directory of files] **********************************************
changed: [win1]

TASK [Debug Msg] ***************************************************************
ok: [win1] => {
    "msg": "Copying logs at - /tmp/cbl-logs/"
}

TASK [Fetch logs] **************************************************************
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_debug_1556888740255.cbllog)
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_error_1556888740258.cbllog)
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_info_1556888740256.cbllog)
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_verbose_1556888740256.cbllog)
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_warning_1556888740257.cbllog)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
win1                       : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

Checking /tmp/cbl-logs/ for copied log files - []
```

Anyone has any idea what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's difficult, but you need to actually look through the error message (second line from the bottom in the Ansible output - the really long one). The reason is in there somewhere. Keep in mind it's usually "metadata, exception reason, stack trace". In this case,  the relevant details (once you pull them out) are:

```
"Exception": {..., "Message": "Illegal characters in path.", ...}
```

so that's your error. Illegal characters in path. We can go further by looking for a stack trace, which is later in the error message:

```
"StackTrace": "   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)\r\n   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.IsReservedDeviceName(String destinationPath)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeItemExists(String path, Boolean& isDirectory, Exception& exception)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeDirectoryExists(String path)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.IsItemContainer(CmdletProvider providerInstance, String path, CmdletProviderContext context)"
```

I usually handle this by opening a python console, pasting it in with triple-quotes and printing it to get rid of the `\r\n` (if necessary you can do this more than once):

```
>>> x = """"   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)\r\n   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.IsReservedDeviceName(String destinationPath)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeItemExists(String path, Boolean& isDirectory, Exception& exception)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeDirectoryExists(String path)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.IsItemContainer(CmdletProvider providerInstance, String path, CmdletProviderContext context)"""
>>> print(x)
"   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.IsReservedDeviceName(String destinationPath)"
   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeItemExists(String path, Boolean& isDirectory, Exception& exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Utils.NativeDirectoryExists(String path)
   at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.IsItemContainer(CmdletProvider providerInstance, String path, CmdletProviderContext context)
```

So overall your error is "illegal characters in path" (presumably, the path of `log_file` or `log_full_path`. Investigate what path you're passing into the script and see if you can make sure it's ascii-only and not containing any special characters.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. So I'm not sure what char is giving the problem, but I tried with moving the files from this "b0bd6c4c-e257-44c1-aeeb-7188f65af9d0_75cr2b68sm664" (big name) to small named directory and it worked. So now, the problem is that it says it copied the directory but I can't see anything copied, however, if I tries to copy specific file from the directory I can see files copied. Is there a way to copy complete directory?

Comment: I don't know Ansible well enough to help with that, sorry. Maybe try asking another, more specific, StackOverflow question?

Answer (score 0):

- I was able to fetch a Kerberos keytab file from my Active Directory Machine (Windows Server 2019) to the ansible master host (CentOS 7).
- Here is my inventory file and the sample playbook.
- In this case argument "***validate_checksum: yes***" is crucial. If you don't use it, playbook will be failed with checksum error.

```js
    02:52 PM  ✔ mhaque on iternal-r8 Δ [ansible-workspace] Ω  cat inventory/invetory 
    [linuxservers]
    crypton.belovedhorizon.com
    helium.belovedhorizon.com

    [winservers]
    avocado.belovedhorizon.com

    [winservers:vars]
    ansible_user=Administrator 
    ansible_password="XXXXXXXXXXX"
    ansible_port=5986
    ansible_connection=winrm
    ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore


    02:52 PM  ✔ mhaque on iternal-r8 Δ [ansible-workspace] Ω  cat chopper.yml 
    ---
    - hosts: all
      #become: yes
      gather_facts: yes
      tasks:
        - name: Fetch the file from the avocado to ansible master
          run_once: yes
          fetch:
            validate_checksum: yes
            src: C:\TMP\krb\others\nfs-crypton.keytab 
            dest: /tmp/nfs-crypton.keytab 
            flat: yes
          when: ansible_hostname == 'avocado
          
          
          
     02:29 PM  ✔ mhaque on iternal-r8 Δ [ansible-workspace] Ω  ansible-playbook -i inventory/invetory chopper.yml -vv
```